# Let $s\in \mathbb{C}$ and $f:G_0\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ holomorphic. Then $f(z)=\lambda z^s$ iff $zf'(z)=sf(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the following claim that I would like to prove:

"Let $s\in \mathbb{C}$ and $f:G_0\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ holomorphic where $G_0=\mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty,0]$. Then the following statements are equivalent:

a) $f(z)=\lambda z^s$ for some $\lambda$ and for all $z\in G_0$

b) $zf'(z)=sf(z)$ for all $z\in G_0$."

I believe that showing a)$\implies$b) is straightforward: take the derivative of both sides of $f(z)=\lambda z^s$ and then multiple both sides by $z$.

To show that b)$\implies$a) my idea has been: since $\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}=\frac{s}{z}$ (where $z\neq 0$ since $z\in G_0$) and $\frac{s}{z}$ has antiderivative $s$log$(z)$. Thus $\exists \alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ such that
$slog(z)+\alpha$ is a branch of the log of $f(z)$. Then

$f(z)=e^{slog(z)+\alpha} \implies e^{slog(z)}e^{\alpha}=f(z) \implies f(z)=e^\alpha e^{slog(z)} \implies f(z)=e^\alpha e^{log(z^s)} \implies f(z)=e^\alpha z^s$.

So letting $\lambda = e^{\alpha}$ we have $f(z)=\lambda z^s$.

However in the above, I assume that $f(z)$ is nonzero for every $z\in G_0$. Does anyone have any advice on how I can show $f$ is nonzero on $G_0$?
I am also worried that some of my above implications may be incorrect, as I'm very unfamiliar with log in the complex plane. Any advice or corrections to the above would be very helpful!

Comment: Either the zero locus is discrete (then use continuity to conclude) or $f$ is identically zero (by the identity theorem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making it a lot more complicated than it needs to be. Using the principal branch of $z^s$ just use the quotient rule to show that the derivative of ${\displaystyle {f(z) \over z^s}}$ is zero. You'll need to use that the derivative of $z^s$ is ${\displaystyle s {z^s \over z}}$.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ has a zero at $w \in G_0$ note that $w \ne 0$ (as $0$ is not in the domain of $f$) and $f(z)=(z-w)^ng(z), n \ge 1$ with $g$ analytic in $G_0$ and $g(w) \ne 0$ but then $f'(z)=n(z-w)^{n-1}g(z)+(w-z)^ng'(z)$ and when you substitute in $zf'=sf$ and divide by $(z-w)^{n-1}$ and take $z \to w$ you get the contradiction $nwg(w)=0$